# How to defer / advance in ember 1.3.1 for configuration based integration testing?

Tags: ember.js

I have a basic QUnit integration test with ember.js 1.3.1

```
test("try to get html", function() {
  App.Bootstrap.init();
  visit("/").then(function() {
    //do some basic asserts here
  });
});
```

The trick is that my App.Bootstrap.init does some configuration setup (before the app boots).

```
App.Bootstrap = Ember.Object.create({
  init: function() {
    App.deferReadiness();
    var configuration = ajaxPromise("/imaging_ui/configuration/", "GET");
    Ember.run.next(function() {
      Ember.RSVP.all([configuration]).then(function(result) {
        //do something w/ the result like setup my configuration globally
        App.advanceReadiness();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

The problem is that since "lazy routing" was applied I can't defer /advance myself anymore because I get the error

> "You cannot defer readiness since the `ready()` hook has already been
>   called"

Here is what my test helper does (basic ember-testing stuff here)

```
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();
```

Note -this works fine in production as the defer / advance work like they would normally (and this init method is invoked inside the following initializer). The below is monkey patched in my test as it runs before I have the chance to mock any xhrs (and because this usually fires an xhr I decided to monkey patch and invoke the init myself before each test run).

```
App.initializer({
  name: 'bootstrap',
  initialize: function() {
    App.Bootstrap.init();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3695), the `visit` helper will call `App.advanceReadiness();` in the first call.

Make sure that you don't have an advanceReadiness in your test setup, like the following:

```
module('my module', {
  setup: function() {
    //...
    // App.advanceReadiness(); can be removed
  }
});
```

Otherwise you'll receive that error.